# View and edit Jupyter Notebook (ipynb) files in terminal

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have some jupyter notebooks (ipynb) on a server, which I connected to with ssh. I can run them using `ipython`. However, if I want to view or edit them, for example using `vim`, it shows me the source code of the file (something like json).

I would like to know if there is any tool or command to view and edit them in terminal?

Comment: I believe not `ipynb` file can only be open with jupyter.

Comment: Hi, I recommend you to use [Jupytext's command line conversions back-and-forth][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion) can synchronize a `ipynb` and a corresponding `py` file using the following command:

```
jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py notebook.ipynb
```

Then after you edited the `py` file, to reflect the changes to the `ipynb` file you need to run the following command:

```
jupytext --sync notebook.ipynb
```

And then you can run the `ipynb` using `ipython`

However, you could create a bash file to sync and run the file after it was edited:

```
fname="$PWD"/"$1".ipynb
jupytext --sync $fname
ipython $fname
```

you can give it an `alias` and run it from any directory.